# Get all divs with a particular class and with a style that is NOT equal to

Tags: jquery

I currently have a bunch of `<div>`’s. The `<div>`’s I’m looking for all have a class `“warning-label”`.

In addition, some of those `<div>`’s have the `style` attribute set to `display:none` some have it set to `display:block` and some simply have an empty `style=””`.

I’d like to get all the `<div>`’s that has the class `“warning-label”` and that **DOES NOT** have the style attribute set to `display:none`.

So far I have the following:

```
var all = $(".warning-label").map(function () {
    return this.innerHTML;
}).get();

console.log(all.join());
```

which brings me back all the `<div>`’s with the `“warning-label”` class. The only thing missing is the **NOT** clause to **NOT** include the ones with `style=” display:none”`.

How could I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: are you looking for visible elements with class `warning-label`? or are you specifically want to make sure that the style `display:none` is set

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was looking for all div's with the *warning-label* class in addition to NOT having the style="display:none".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
$("div.warning-label:visible")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:visible` pseudo selector.

ie. `$(".warning-label:visible")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `.not()` to do just what you're looking for:

```
$(".warning-label").not(':hidden')
```

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Aq3X5/1/